# Backup script permission issue

Tags: permissions, backup

I have a server with a user named `deploy-user` and have written a backup script to backup a number of websites associated with this user. However one of the sites I'm trying to backup has a directory `/home/usera/web/www.example.com/some/random_dir` is owned by `apache-data-user`.

What permissions would I give `deploy-user` to be able to backup that directory. Options I am aware of are either:

- Running the script as `root`, which I don't really want to do.
- Adding `apache-data-user` and `deploy-user` to the same group. But then `apache-data-user` will have to many permissions.

Has anyone got a suggestion of the best way to backup this directory?

Answer (score 1):

find default apache user's group in /etc/groups

and add deploy-user to that group

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put deploy-user and apache-data-user into the same group then [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is definitely the way to go, unless you want to use ACL. Note that such a group will probably only need read permissions to the directory you're referring to.

Another option would be to use sudo to give the deploy-user some **very restricted** rights to only perform backup operations as root.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) enabled, give `deploy-user` the right to read `/home/usera/web/www.example.com/some/random_dir` and its contents. To enable ACLs, you may need to add the `acl` option to the entry for the filesystem in `/etc/fstab` and install your distribution's `acl` package.

Under Linux, the following commands give `deploy-user` the right to read and traverse the whole hierarchy rooted at `/home/usera/web`:

```
setfacl -d -m user:deploy-user:rx -R /home/usera/web
setfacl -m user:deploy-user:rx -R /home/usera/web
```