# How can I execute any command as a normal user without sudo?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, sudo

Is it possible to assign the setuid bit to sudo in order to execute any command as a normal user?

Let's suppose that we have the user test and then:

```
test@test$ apt-get update
```

But I don't want to use sudo nor modify the sudoers file, is this possible using only the setuid bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/159007/132098

Answer (score 18):

If your account has `sudo` rights, then there's no need to mess with the suid bit. The following assumes Bash as your interactive shell, so you may have to modify steps 2&3 depending on what you use.

---

1. Add these to the end of /etc/sudoers

   ```
   USERNAME HOST_NAME = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
   USERNAME HOST_NAME = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/shutdown
   ```
2. Add these to your ~/.bashrc

   ```
   alias shutdown='sudo shutdown'
   alias apt-get='sudo apt-get'
   ```
3. Reload the startup config for the current session.

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. Now you can run the commands as a normal user without being prompted for a root/sudo password (and therefore, eliminate the need to know the password altogether).

   ```
   $ apt-get update
   $ apt-get upgrade
   $ shutdown -h now
   ```

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer...

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the correction. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Instead of changing `/etc/sudoers`, I would put the additional lines in `/etc/sudoers.d/local`. Keeps the original file clean and doesn't break on updates.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: You **can't** execute arbitrary admin commands without either

- a sudo, or
- being root.

Long answer: You must either have `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`, or log as root. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password.

```
visudo
```

then add a line

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

As requested, if you want to run, as root, a specific **binary** file, you might use

```
chown root:wheel /usr/binary
chmod u+s /usr/binary
```

however, if program you want to run as root without sudo is a shell (or a python, awk, perl), you can't.

beware of pitfall, on my main ubuntu `/usr/bin/shutdown` is a link to `/sbin/systemctl`.

I would need to copy the later to the former before applying chmod/chown above.

Comment: For security, you can also set the `NOPASSWD` argument for specific commands as `user ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot`

Comment: @Peschke but you still need to use `sudo poweroff`, `sudo reboot`. The OP wanted to get rid of the `sudo` part.

Comment: @telcoM yep, the answer above covered that. My comment was just expanding the answer.

Comment: @Peschke I see, my mistake, sorry about the noise then.

Comment: Does this remove the need for `sudo` for any command?
Otherwise, how to achieve the same, but for one specific command (or an arbitrary set of them)?

Comment: I don´t understand, from your answer (and even your last comment), how would you remove the need for `sudo` just for one command, say, `pm-hibernate`. Would you mind adding a specific example?
Note: In my previous comment, "Otherwise, ..." should actually read "If so, ..."