# How to start with sudo privileges every time I run terminal with CTRL+ALT+T

Tags: command-line, terminal, sudo, kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Kali Linux and I want to start with sudo privileges every time I run the terminal using CTRL+ALT+T.

I tried this solution but it's not working:

[is-there-a-way-to-stop-having-to-write-sudo-for-every-little-thing-in-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/is-there-a-way-to-stop-having-to-write-sudo-for-every-little-thing-in-linux)

Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously there is a way to do it: The question you reference has several solutions. You can't expect the other users to read through all that, and if anybody answers here, there is a good chance that the answer doesn't work for you. To enable people to help you, state which solutions you tried, and how they failed. "not working" is not a problem description. A problem is described as follows: (1) which steps did you take (2) what did you expect to happen (3) what unexpected results did you get.

Comment: Are you the sole person using your computer and do you mind if your password is in plain, readable text?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really such a thing as "*sudo privileges*". There are root privileges, which the `sudo` command can grant. Or you could log in as root directly, but this isn't generally recommended.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to type your password every time you type sudo, you can edit sudoers file by running `sudo visudo` then making sure the line `razimbres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` is present.

If you absolutely do not want to type sudo evry time (which is not recommanded because all your actions will have root privileges), you can add `sudo su` at the end of your `.bashrc` (or equivalent) file.

Comment: Thanks Clemente, is there a way to start terminal at root@kali every time ?

Comment: Noooo! Please don't ever recommend `sudo su`. And certainly not at the end of your `.bashrc`

Comment: @roaima I did not recommend it (as it is written between brackets) but I answer the original question :)

Answer (score -2):

`echo "<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/010_$user-nopasswd`

Comment: Could you describe what this does exactly and how it solves the user's issue? Note that it appears as if you are giving the user the rights to execute _any_ command with `sudo` without having to give a password.  You should probably explain why you think this is an adequate measure.

Comment: Since you appear to be relying on the `$user` variable being set, why not use it as part of the `echo` command itself? As-is, the answer is not copy-paste-able, since the literal `<username>` will not match any valid username. Additionally, `$user` is not guaranteed to contain the current username; perhaps you wanted $USER?